# Is there a "Show Mask" keyboard shortcut in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm wondering if this is possible in both the **Liquify** interface and in the regular **Layers** (layer masks).

I'd like to be able to toggle the mask overlay without having to move the cursor away from my work.

Comment: Hi, is it for Mac?

Comment: @MichaelClark Can you explain why this is more relevant to graphic design as opposed to photography? I asked it here because masking isn't something I worry about very much when doing graphic design work.

Comment: @David Yes, I am on a Mac.

Comment: @rhaphazard Because you haven't placed it in a context of solving a problem that is specifically about creating a photograph as opposed to graphic design in general, where you might be dealing with an already existing photograph as you integrate it into a graphic design project.

Comment: @MichaelClark Okay, that makes sense. Is there a way for me to move the question myself? Or do we just wait for more votes?

Comment: Moderators are the only ones that can migrate a question. In the end my opinion may not be the prevailing one, so at this point you just sit tight and wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the '\' key (backslash). It will toggle the masked area on/off by showing it as a red overlay (varying shades dependent on strength).

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm surprised this was so difficult to find. But as soon as I add "backslash" to my search so many results that I didn't see before popup.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one by default, but it's easy enough to add your own.
Edit menu > Keyboard shortcuts > reveal Layer

[image]

Comment: This isn't what the person asked. This turns on and off the mask. They asked for the Mask View.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>click</kbd> on the mask.

Comment: Hello Marius, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your answer. Please, don't use ALL CAPS in your posts here, it reads like shouting and is considered very rude. For keyboard shortcuts we have the custom <kbd></kbd> tags. As you are new, I recommend you have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help] to understand more about this site and Stack Exchange in general. Thanks and see you 'round!

Comment: Yes, this is the only way for using the `Toggle layer mask on/off as rubylith (layer mask must be selected)` function with keyboard layouts which don't have the key for ``\``. One example is Croatian keyboard layout where there is `Ž` at the place of backslash.